# Hyper-V multi-homed host NIC?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, nic

In Microsoft's Hyper-V virtualization engine, is it possible to have a multi-homed host NIC (i.e. with several different IP addresses) then have several guest VMs, each of which corresponds to one of the IP addresses from the host?

My scenario is that I want to publish several VMs out to the internet and I want each VM to respond to a different fixed, publicly-routable IP address. The gateway router will be in "bridge mode" so it will simply pass all traffic to the physical LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Ah no. In Hyper-V the hosts define the IP-Adresses, the phsyical NIC works like the ethernet port on a switch. So, just set up a virtual network to a physical NIC and then set up virtual NICS to that virtual network which can be multi homed.

Comment: Ah, right. So if I understand that correctly, simply by setting the IP addresses on the guest VMs, I should get the effect I want, yes? I think what you're saying is that Hyper-V takes care of configuring the host NIC for me.

Comment: No. There is no configuration. The host NIC is used as a virtual switch. It does not have IP addresses. It works in bridge mode to a virtual switch which then the virtual NIC's attach to. All ARP traffic is handled by the virtual NICs.